# Lapply incorrect number of dimensions in a list of data frames..?

Tags: r, list, filter, error-handling, lapply

I have a large list of several hundreds of data frames and trying to filter rows from between two values containing a pattern VALUE1 and VALUE2 in the column Z. Like this:

```
weight | height | Z
---------------------------
62      100      NA
65      89       NA
59      88       randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
66      92       NA
64      90       NA
64      87       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
57      84       NA
68      99       NA
59      82       NA
60      87       srebmunmodnarVALUE1txetmodnar
61      86       NA
63      84       srebmunmodnarVALUE2txetmodnar
```

And after filtering I would get:

```
59      88       randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
66      92       NA
64      90       NA
64      87       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
60      87       srebmunmodnarVALUE1txetmodnar
61      86       NA
63      84       srebmunmodnarVALUE2txetmodnar
```

The code I'm using is:

```
lapply(df, function(x){
  start <- which(grepl("VALUE1", x$Z))
  end   <- which(grepl("VALUE2", x$Z))
  rows  <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(start), function(y){start[y]:end[y]}))
  return(df[rows,])})
```

But whenever I try to run the script, I get an error message saying:

**Error in df[rows, ] : incorrect number of dimensions**

Why does this happen and how can I get around it..?

EDIT: Added a minimal sample data of the actual datasheet (the first data frame and first element of the list, VALUE2 will follow VALUE 1 always at some point)

```
> head(tbl[[1]])
# A tibble: 6 × 4
      t speed   off Z                                                                       
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                                                   
1  27.3  27.8 0.485 "{\"type\":\"M\",\"msg\":\"VALUE1\",\"time\":27.2498,\"dist\":0.410454}"
2  27.4  27.8 0.457  NA                                                                     
3  27.5  27.8 0.430  NA                                                                     
4  27.6  27.8 0.402  NA                                                                     
5  27.7  27.8 0.374  NA                                                                     
6  27.8  27.8 0.347  NA
```

Comment: lapply needs a list as first input. is df (at the beginning of code `lapply(df, function(x){` ) is a list?

Comment: Yes, the df/tbl is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are equal number of 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', get the position index of 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2', separately with `grep`, create a sequence (`:`) by looping over the corresponding positions in `Map`, `unlist` and use the sequence to subset the data

```
df1[sort(unique(unlist(Map(`:`, grep("VALUE1", df1$Z),
       grep("VALUE2", df1$Z))))),]
```

-output

```
 weight height                             Z
3      59     88 randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
4      66     92                          <NA>
5      64     90                          <NA>
6      64     87 randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
10     60     87 srebmunmodnarVALUE1txetmodnar
11     61     86                          <NA>
12     63     84 srebmunmodnarVALUE2txetmodnar
```

---

If the `df` is a single data.frame,  when we loop over the `data.frame` with `lapply`, it will be looping over the columns and thus each `list` element is a vector.  Therefore, there is no `x$Z`.  Each `x` will be the corresponding column

If it is a `list`, then the error can occur when there are cases with no 'VALUE1' or 'VALUE2' or if the number of 'VALUE1' matches are not equal to 'VALUE2'.  It may be better to check those elements before doing the `:`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(weight = c(62L, 65L, 59L, 66L, 64L, 64L, 57L, 
68L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 63L), height = c(100L, 89L, 88L, 92L, 90L, 
87L, 84L, 99L, 82L, 87L, 86L, 84L), Z = c(NA, NA,
 "randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext", 
NA, NA, "randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext", NA, NA, NA, 
"srebmunmodnarVALUE1txetmodnar", 
NA, "srebmunmodnarVALUE2txetmodnar")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but for some reason I still get the same "incorrect number of dimensions" -error message. I provided a minimal look at my actual datasheet if that somehow helps to solve the issue!